# How to create 2 Favicon in One website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to create 2 favicon in a site?

/images/favicon/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

So i'll be creating 2 homepage, the 2nd homepage will have different favicon.
they only want to see which favicon is better.

Comment: If you are writing the site yourself in simply html, if so, just change the favicon declaration on the 2 pages - `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" />`. If your not then provide more information in your questions as to how you are making your site.

Comment: I guess that you could use javascript and set that if some condition is accomplished the favicon will be favicon1.ico, else favicon2.ico

Comment: *they* really do not need an up and running website to *see which favicon is better*. Create a screenshot, open photoshop, paste the two different images and send the cropped previews.

Comment: can have as many favicons as there are pages. note that browsers tend to cache favicons very easily and putting a cachebuster in the url can help

Answer (score 4):

You can *wow* your customer:

paste this before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
var favicons = [
    "/images/favicon/favicon.ico",
    "/images/favicon/favicon2.ico"
];
var n = 0;
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.which===70) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.type = 'image/x-icon';
        link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
        link.href = favicons[++n%2];
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

**and tell them to hit <kbd>F</kbd> on the keyboard.**

---

Said that, you can always create two favicons, `favicon.ico` and `favicon2.ico`, and call the desired one. I mean you *don't have* to call your image exactly `favicon`. Simply get the right one

<sub>indexTest1.html</sub>

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

<sub>indexTest2.html</sub>

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```